# Meaning of "as close as you can get with safe sex"

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context

What does "as close as you can get with safe sex" mean? I read this sentence in "Hannibal" from Thomas Harris, the original is

> Our informant's close to the family situation, like, he's very close, as close as you can get with safe sex.

Is this phrase an idiom?

Comment: Compare it to how close you can get without safe sex.

Comment: Not an idiom, no, but I've seen other analogies to things being extremely close without actually touching by referring to something extremely thin. For example a 'cigarette paper' apart.

Comment: The difference between *safe sex* and *unsafe sex* is the thickness of a condom or rubber or whatever you want to call it. That's *how close*. It's an *analogy*.

Comment: It's a stupid analogy. "Safe sex" is very much akin to "decaffeinated coffee": _ersatz_. Two of my wives were unable to conceive. I had safe sex with one without a polyurethane barrier. The other one gave me a genital wart. The first was faithful, the second wasn't.

Comment: Thanks, guys! The analogy like this is really hard to understand for someone who isn't a native speaker.

Comment: This is Too Localised (or perhaps just Off Topic). It's not about English as such - it's just a matter of having sufficient powers of understanding to recognise the metaphoric juxtaposition of social and physical "closeness".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an idiom, but rather a coarse metaphor, referring to being separated by something as unobtrusive as a condom (supposedly feels like it's not even there!).